# jquery drop shadow plugin?

Tags: jquery, dropshadow

Is there any drop shadow plugin for jquery?

Seems there was but is no more...

Any help?

Also, is it possible to use jquery in a PHP file ? (I create a table in the php file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You correctly summed up the current state. There used to be a jQuery UI drop shadow component, but not any more.

If you're looking for any way to create drop shadows, just Google for "CSS drop shadow" and you'll find tons of results.

**Edit:** Yes, you can use jQuery in a PHP file, or pretty much any other server-side scripting language. I recommend writing your Javascript in a separate foo.js file and importing it.

In the future, please ask a new question instead of editing, if the topic isn't directly related.

Answer (score 3):

A remnant of the DropShadow plugin still exists on googlecode: http://code.google.com/p/dropshadow/. The code is old but it might still be salvageable if not immediately usable.

There's the "Box Shadow" plugin that seems more up-to-date: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/boxshadow

My only other suggestion is to take a look at jQuery UI's internal implementation of drop shadows: http://dev.jqueryui.com/changeset/1814
They seem to be planning to add the functionality as a widget at some point: http://wiki.jqueryui.com/Shadow

Comment: The Box Shadow code was pretty good.  however, I had to modify it for elements that were center aligned.  Martin's code made some presumptions it shouldn't have.