# div shadow with jquery

Tags: jquery, shadow

Is there any plugin for use a shadow effect on a div?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

The to search for keyword is "drop shadow".

Duplicates: [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589749/jquery-drop-shadow-plugin) [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165446/where-can-i-find-a-good-jquery-drop-shadow-plugin)

Googling [JQuery drop shadow](http://www.google.de/#hl=en&source=hp&q=jquery+drop+shadow&btnG=Google+Search&aq=f&oq=jquery+drop+shadow&fp=4fc34adcbfaca52f) turns up a number of good results. There is at least [one plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/DropShadow).

Answer (score 1):

[http://plugins.jquery.com/project/dropcurves](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/DropShadow)

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/DropShadow

There are numerious plugins for rendering drop shadows under page elements via jQuery, all of which were found via a quick Google search.